# Stretching a small background image in CSS

Tags: css, coding-style, background-image, dreamweaver

I am having issues understanding the correct syntax for scaling or expanding and image in CSS.

I have tried many things but i can't get it to work properly.

The code that I am currently using is

```
background:url(../images/body_bg1.jpg) fixed repeat-y; width:100%; height:100%;}
```

currently with the code above the image is tiled across the left side of the page when i use `repeat-y` it tiles it across the top of the page.

From what i have read i should be able to use the syntax above to have my image fixed and stretched am i missing something here?

Also with the code above is it OK to format the code like this so it is easier to read?

```
background:url(../images/body_bg1.jpg) fixed repeat-y; 
width:100%; 
height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature just got implemented with css3. So it won't run in slighty old browsers.

```
div
{
background-image:url('myBG.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
}
```

Check out this site. Its a pretty cool site, if you ask me.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

EDIT: In older browsers its simply not possible without a workaround with the usual

```
<image src=""/>
```

in the background of your content.

Comment: awesome! that worked perfect. I looked at every other page on that site but somehow i missed that one. 

Since this is a new feature, what will happen with older browsers. I can google it but i figured you might have the answer :)

Thank you for your assistance

Comment: also to make the image fixed or static, do i use fixed somewhere in the syntax you provided?

Comment: It will ignore the cover and display the image in his original size one time, since no-repeat is implemented in older browsers.

Comment: Checkout the possible background properties at w3schools yourself. Read them all and you got your overview. It probably is already fixed and I don't know if "scroll" will even work.

Comment: thank you for your assistance, i now have a better understanding

Answer (score 1):

Actually to have the background stretched you have to specify the width and height as in the element or use contain:

```
div
{
background-image:url('image.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:100% 100%;
/*background-size:contain;*/
}
```

Using cover will stretch one side and overflow the other one

Comment: ahh so this is the best way and is this compatible with older browsers with using the % instead of cover?

Comment: The whole background-size property is CSS3 and thus not compatible with older browser. The sizing problem is a well know issue with css1. So you ran into a thing webdevelopers are getting upset about since years.

Comment: xeed is right. His answer is right as well. The difference of using percentage over cover, is that cover stretches one side and overflows the other one, while percentages controls both sides, since you need to stretch not to fit, i think you need to use percentage or contain
You have to test them all and decide what the best for you

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the CSS `background-size` property here methinks:

```
background-size:[width] [height];
background-repeat:repeat-y;
```

The second value will be set to auto if you supply only one.